Integrity constraint violation when filtering sales order grid by Purchasedate Magento2
I’ve implemented a custom plugin to display additional custom fields in the sales order grid and its values, and it is functioning as expected. However, when applying a filter on the 'Purchase Date,' I encounter the following error:
Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'created_at' in where clause is ambiguous at /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php:90.
I have already reviewed related discussions on GitHub(https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/38818), specifically this issue, but would appreciate any additional guidance on resolving this error."
di.xml
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <plugin name="showErpStatusInOrderGrid" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactoryPlugin" sortOrder="1"/>
</type>


Vendor\Module\Plugin\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactoryPlugin
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory;

class CollectionFactoryPlugin
{
    public function afterGetReport(
        CollectionFactory $subject,
        $collection,
        $requestName
    ) {
        if ($requestName == 'sales_order_grid_data_source') {
            $collection->join(
                ['sales_order' => 'sales_order'],
                'main_table.entity_id=sales_order.entity_id',
                ['shipping_slots','order_device','shipping_date','inventory_source','coupon_code']
            );
           
        }

        return $collection;
    }
}


The issue was resolved by implementing the following solution
Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sales_order_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">sales_order_grid</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order</argument>
        </arguments>
</type>

Vendor/Module/Model/ResourceModel/Order/Grid/Collection.php
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid;

use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface as FetchStrategy;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface as EntityFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface as EventManager;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection as OriginalCollection;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface as Logger;

/**
 * Order grid extended collection
 */
class Collection extends OriginalCollection
{
    /**
     * Constructor for initializing collection
     *
     * @param EntityFactory $entityFactory
     * @param Logger $logger
     * @param FetchStrategy $fetchStrategy
     * @param EventManager $eventManager
     * @param string $mainTable
     * @param string $resourceModel
     */
    public function __construct(
        EntityFactory $entityFactory,
        Logger $logger,
        FetchStrategy $fetchStrategy,
        EventManager $eventManager,
        $mainTable = 'sales_order_grid',
        $resourceModel = \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order::class
    ) {
        parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $mainTable, $resourceModel);

        // Add custom filter mappings
        $this->addFilterToMap('order_device', 'so.order_device');
        $this->addFilterToMap('shipping_slots', 'so.shipping_slots');
        $this->addFilterToMap('shipping_date', 'so.shipping_date');
        $this->addFilterToMap('coupon_code', 'so.coupon_code');
        $this->addFilterToMap('inventory_source', 'so.inventory_source');
    }

    /**
     * Render filters before query execution
     */
    protected function _renderFiltersBefore()
    {
        $joinTable = $this->getTable('sales_order');

        // Join the required columns from the sales_order table
        $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
            ['so' => $joinTable],
            'main_table.entity_id = so.entity_id',
            ['shipping_slots', 'order_device', 'shipping_date', 'inventory_source', 'coupon_code']
        );

        // Call parent method to apply any additional filtering
        parent::_renderFiltersBefore();
    }
}



Try this approach
di.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sales_order_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">sales_order_grid</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>

Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection.php
    protected function _renderFiltersBefore()
    {
        // place your JOIN here
        $joinTable = $this->getTable('sales_order');
        $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
            ['sales_order_table' => $joinTable],
            'main_table.entity_id = sales_order_table.entity_id',
            ...

        parent::_renderFiltersBefore();
    }

And give a look to addFilterToMap method, in the case you still get the ambiguous error

Try to use your code/modification with afterSearch plugin [ Class Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Reporting ]
